# Links not rendering when using font awesome in D3

Tags: d3.js, font-awesome

I'm currently building an app that graphs out github repos using Mike Bostock's D3 layout example found here: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

I'm trying to render a font-awesome font instead of the svg circle and I believe this is the code that is rendering the circle:

```
nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
  .attr("r", 1e-6)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });
```

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416749/adding-fontawesome-icons-to-a-d3-graph) and when I tried to use that code, it successfully rendered the font-awesome icons, but now the linkable text, though rendered, is hidden for some reason:

[image: linkable text rendered on the page but not visible]

I tried manipulating the code but can't figure out how to get the text node and link text to also render.

Also, I have a feeling that this other code may be interfering with my appends and causing this error. Here is it is in full:

```
nodeEnter.append("svg:a")
  // make the links open in a new page
  .attr("target", "_blank")

  .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { 
    console.log('d.name -->', d.name);
    // d.data.path "" + d.name
    var url = "https://" + URLtoArr[0] + "/" + URLtoArr[1] + "/" + URLtoArr[2] + "/" + "tree/master" + "/";
    // if path is set (if it is NOT the root node), add it on to the end
    if(d.data !== undefined) {
      url += d.data.path; 
    }
    return url; 
    // https://github.com/AndyLampert/repository-file-tree-generator/blob/master/public/css/main.css
  })

  .append("svg:text")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
  .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
```

Finally, here is my current working app on heroku:
http://github-file-tree-generator.herokuapp.com/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `.style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);` == almost invisible although not technically transparent.  Some examples recommend it to make clickable but invisible content (although you should really use the pointer-events property for that).  I have no idea why you're using it here, but if you get rid of that line the text should show up fine!

Comment: Actually, could you post on this thread so I can mark it as answered? Thanks.

Comment: sure.  I'd actually marked it for closure as just a simple typo, but since d3/svg posts don't often get properly closed, we might as well not have it showing up as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text icons are showing up, as you could tell from the DOM and from selecting text, but they are nearly completely transparent.

`.style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);` == almost invisible although not technically hidden

Some examples recommend using an almost-zero opacity to create clickable but invisible content (although you should really use the pointer-events property for that).  You must have copied it over by accident.