# Including FontAwesome icons into SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, font-awesome

I'd made all that Duopixes said in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984007/how-do-i-include-a-font-awesome-icon-in-my-svg/14986420#14986420) but it didn't help. The icon shows as text still.
Here my HTML:

```
<g class="info-container" transform="translate(240,283)">
    <text class="svg-icon" x="-60" y="0">&#xf040</text>
</g>
```

and

```
.svg-icon{
    font-family: FontAwesome;
  }
```

The style is applied to the text element and FontAwesome.css is attached to the page. What I've done wrong?

**UPDATE:**
I'm creating svg-elements via D3.js library. And that was the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416749/adding-fontawesome-icons-to-a-d3-graph). In a D3-chart we need to use \ufXXX format for an icon text.

```
infoGroup.append("text").attr("class", "svg-icon").text("\uf005");
```