# showing fa icon in text of SVG d3j jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, svg

I have been creating some charts using `d3j`, and I am trying to show `fa- icon` in the text, What I am doing is

```
  svg.select('#g_axis').selectAll('text')
      .data(dataset.slice(startSet, endSet))
      .enter()
      .append('text')
      .attr('font-family', 'FontAwesome')
      .attr('x', paddingLeft)
      .attr('y', lineSpacing + dataHeight / 2)
      .html(function (d) {
        console.log(d.measure);
        return d.measure + "<i class='red main-sidebar fa fa-chain-broken'></i>";
      })
      .attr('transform', function (d, i) {
        return 'translate(0,' + ((lineSpacing + dataHeight) * i) + ')';
      })
      .attr('class', 'ytitle');
```

I tried to add font-family to fontAwesome as it was suggested in some stackoverflow answers,

and Added as

`.html(function (d) {
            console.log(d.measure);
            return d.measure + "<i class='red main-sidebar fa fa-chain-broken'></i>";
          })`

Its returning only measure, but not icon which should be red, classes are available, when I inspect element, there is also `text` tag with `i` class but icon still not visible, In code above I append the fa icon with `measure`, Just to try it but basically am giving measure such value as

`"abc <i class='red fa fa-chain-broken'></i>"`..

When there was `.text(function(d))` it was showing tag itself but after doing `.html` now its not showing the tag but not giving the expected output as well. Any help will be appreciated.

The question mentioned as duplicate is doing all text as a fa-icon, where I have a string and concatenating fa-icon with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding FontAwesome icons to a D3 graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416749/adding-fontawesome-icons-to-a-d3-graph)

Comment: you can clearly see my purpose is totally diffrent and I also added that i have already added font family to fontawesome.. Still you marked it duplicate