# How can I add an image inside C3.js piechart slices?

Tags: c3.js

I want to add an icon inside C3.js piechart slices. I want this:

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This should add icons using fontawesome

```
d3.selectAll(".c3-chart-arcs text").each(function(d) {
  // your update code here as it was in your example
  d3.select(this).append('text')
  .attr('font-family', 'FontAwesome')
  .attr('font-size', function(d) { return '2em'} )
    .text(function(d) { return '\uf118' });  
});
```

More info - [Adding FontAwesome icons to a D3 graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416749/adding-fontawesome-icons-to-a-d3-graph)