# How to properly add FontAwesome icons on d3 nodes?

Tags: d3.js, font-awesome

I am trying to add icons on my text nodes from font-awesome. Instead of showing me the proper icon, the whole html gets class `fontawesome-i2svg-active fontawesome-i2svg-complete` and i get a big question mark/exclamation mark are shown on the page.

I tried applying the following code which i found as a reply on fontawesome github page.

```
const textEnter = textElements
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .attr('x', 15)
  .attr('y', -17)
  .attr('fill', 'black')
  .attr('class', 'fa')
  .attr('font-size', '20')
  .text('\uf2b9');
```

EDIT:

The solution which is offered here doesn't work:

[Adding FontAwesome icons to a D3 graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416749/adding-fontawesome-icons-to-a-d3-graph)

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the Font-Awesome font?
Double check with the inspector that FontAwesome is set as the `font-family`

Another solution would be to use font awesomes svg files as images.
or depending on your setup you could even inline the svg files directly in the source code.